# Gradle Build Speeds

Tags: android, gradle

I created a new project in Android Studio yesterday, after creating it with just one blank activity it consistently too in excess of 14 Minutes to build. Looking at a previous project that has multiple activities that compiles in less than 4 Seconds I noticed the following differences in my build.gradle file

Fast Compile(4 Seconds) has the following

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

Slow Compile (>14 Minutes) has the following

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
}
```

I changed the new project to use the dependencies from the old project and surprise it to built in less than 4 seconds.

What is going on here? Am I doing something wrong, missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add all your gradle scripts?
With which repositories did you worked with, jcenter or maven?
Have you tried to switched between them? How much time it will take to build the project again?

Answer (score 0):

When you compile project, it checks dependencies and download if! required. Thats whould be the reason why it took. Since downloading operation is executed once, next builds will be more speedy.

On the other hand if you did download operation before (which is previous project), gradle can use from local disk. It makes it faster.

Comment: I can understand you answer, but that does not explain why when as a test I updated my original project to use the same dependencies as the new project its build time slowed to 14 to 15 Minutes, and I did some testing last night and consistently the "slow" set was 14 to 15 minutes every time I did a build.

Comment: They are different dependencies as their versions are different. (You can check the suffixs). But have no idea since it takes 15 mins for every build. Sorry :(